# Frequency analysis of values produced by generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I'm doing some analysis of images, and I have a generator that gives me all pixels in image:

```
def pixels_g(img):
    w, h = img.shape
    for y in range(0, h):
        for x in range(0, w):
            yield img[y][x]
```

It's output if converted to list would be something like

```
[0, 1, 2, 5, 240, 5, ... ]
```

Now I'd like to get "frequency table" for it:

```
{
    0: 0,
    1: 5,
    2: 10,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    #snip
    255: 7
}
```

I've found some useful options in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python), but they all work with list, and I don't think that creating a list from my generator is a good idea - it can have **millions of elements**.

I'm therefore looking for a way to do this while preserving the benefits of generator. I'll process many images and don't want to hog resources too much.

Comment: a defaultdict and count as you go?

Comment: collections.counter strikes yet again. This question definitely has at least a dozen duplicates.

Comment: @OlehPrypin will collections.Counter take advantage of it being a generator?

Comment: The only difference may be that it doesn't save zero-count elements...

Answer (score 0):

Use Counter from "collections". It works with any iterable, not just lists.

```
from collections import Counter

pixels = pixels_g(img)
c = Counter(pixels)

print c[4]
```

If you need to reuse the contents of 'pixels' generator instance after running it through Counter, use 'tee' from itertools:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import tee

(pixels, hist) = tee(pixels_g(img))
c = Counter(pixels)
# can use hist for something else
```

Comment: that would consume the generator

Comment: Works, except I don't get zeros for missing values. `dict.get(num, 0)` might deal with it, I guess... but it's a hack

Comment: @PadraicCunningham what do you mean, consume?

Comment: I mean if you called counter on it and tried using the generator after you would get nothing

Comment: @MightyPork A Counter object already returns 0 for missing items, so `.get()` is not required.

Comment: Not if I convert it to a dict. I intend to plot it as histogram, there it might be a problem.

Comment: if you need a dict() that explicitly contains 0 counts, you could use a defaultdict and init it with something like `zip(range(0,256), itertools.repeat(0, times=256))`, maybe